# Running jupyter notebook in a HPC environment

Tags: port, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, hpc

I'm trying to host a Jupyter server on HPC.
I submit notebook as a job using following command:

```
bsub -q smp -m smp0 -n 32 -J notebook jupyter notebook
```

When I log into `smp0` node I can see the job running.
I have configured the notebook to run on port 39090. However, when i try to access the notebook on `http://smp_ip_adddress:39090` I get 'This site can’t be reached' error on my browser (chrome). Also, the notebook doesn't log any GET request.

However, when I launch the notebook on the head node (by simply executing `jupyter notebook`) I can easily access it remotely from anywhere on LAN.

So, I think the problem is that I can't connect to compute node directly or the port 39090 on compute node is blocked.

I ran nmap and found the following result for the compute node's ip:

```
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind
```

Interestingly I can ping the compute node from my remote computer on LAN (I didn't expect ping to work because usually compute nodes are on HPC internal network , but its doesn't seem so in this case).

Now there is two probable routes I can take. Any suggestions for any of these two options are welcome:

1) Some sort of port forwarding to access the notebook on the compute node.
2) Running only the kernel on compute node and notebook on head node and somehow connect them.

Please let me know if I'm note clear or this question is too vague and help me find a solution.

Thanks.